# Seaborn diverging_palette(): colours appear different than expected

Tags: seaborn, heatmap, color-palette

I'm trying to create a Seaborn `heatmap()` of a correlation matrix using a custom `diverging_palette()`. I'd like to have **100% red** at the extremes, and **100% white** at the center.

I used the code below, but I get **pink** at the extremes and **light-grey** at the center (see screenshot). I'd say `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)` should give red? What am I missing?

```python
corr_matrix = ames_train_cleaned.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).corr()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
my_palette = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=0, h_pos=0, s=100, l=50, sep=100, as_cmap=True)

_ = sns.heatmap(data=corr_matrix,
                ax=ax,
                mask=np.triu(corr_matrix, k=1),
                cmap=my_palette,
                center=0)
```

[image: correlation heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... I found this Q&A on StackOverflow which pointed me in the right direction.

[Seaborn diverging_palette with more than 2 color tones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682797/seaborn-diverging-palette-with-more-than-2-color-tones)

Replaced the definition of `my_palette` in my code-snippet with this:

`my_palette = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='dummy', colors=['blue','white','red'])`

This works perfectly, but I'm still not sure why the **red** wasn't **red** in my initial solution...